# How does Java prevent an as yet unassigned instance from being garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Example:

```
public void foo() {
    A a = new A();
}
```

What if there is this sequence of events?

1. Java allocates memory for A.
2. The `A()` constructor runs. Now there is an instance in the heap.
3. The GC runs.
4. There are no refs to the object and it is removed before being assigned to `a`.

How does it prevent this from occurring? I would greatly appreciate links to article where it is explained.

Comment: There's a reference to it on the stack. That reference will be copied into `a`, then `a` has a reference to it.

Comment: The sentence “Now there is an instance in the heap.” belongs to point one. After allocating memory for an object, there is an object in the heap memory, even if not initialized. But for example, when the constructor fails with an exception, the garbage collector still needs to run, to reclaim the uninitialized object’s memory. And the logic of point four is obviously flawed. If there were “no refs to the object”, how could you assign a such a reference to `a`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to answer once you know that the [**call stack**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is traversed by the garbage collector (GC). So when it traverses the stack of the method `foo`, it simply *knows* that there are [references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)) (`a`) pointing to that heap memory.

In order to know what is garbage, the GC has to first scan everything that is alive. Since there are references pointing to that memory (the `new A()`); that is treated alive, at least until `a` is used, somewhere, by some thread.